# Multiple Row JQuery Dialog Issue

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I am getting critical issue while working on JQuery.

Do `$(this).dialog('close');` removes content which is being bind to display? If yes then how can I prevent this.

Below is my code.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
function cool_function(event){
    //alert(event.data.param1);

    alert($('#'+event.data.param2).html());

    //var dialog = $('#'+event.data.param2).children('#content').html();
    $('#'+event.data.param2).children('#content').dialog({
                    model : true,
                    autoOpen: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Save": function() {
                            alert('Content Will be Saved');

                        },
                        "Cancel":  function() {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });

    $('#'+event.data.param2).children('#content').dialog('open');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
<h1>Existing Users:</h1>
<table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<thead>
<tr class="ui-widget-header ">
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Password</th>
<th>Comment</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>John Doe</td>
<td>john.doe@example.com</td>
<td>johndoe1</td>
<td class="click" id="clickTest1">
    <script>
    $("#clickTest1").click({param1: "Hello Darshak", param2: "clickTest1"}, cool_function);
    </script>
    <div>
        <img id='' src="gray.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div id='content' title='John Doe' style="display:none;">
        <div><textarea>Hello this is Text Area</textarea></div>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ketan B</td>
<td>ketan.b@example.com</td>
<td>ket1</td>
<td class="click" id="clickTest2">
    <script>
    $("#clickTest2").click({param1: "Hello Ketan", param2: "clickTest2"}, cool_function);
    </script>
    <div>
        <img id='' src="gray.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div id='content' title='Ketan B' style="display:none;">
        <div><textarea>One more text area Hurrey!!!</textarea></div>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now issue is, Check the alert in code when I load page first time. alert will give me whole div code including the `content` id code.

Once the `content` displayed on dialog bar, I close or cancel that dialog then try to click the same first row again and it doesn't have `content` div at all and I could not get dialog again.

Below is screen shot to understand it better.

Dialog box 1

[image]

Dialog display only first time when I click on comment image

[image]

**Update - Answer**

I got my answer. Here are the changes in same.

Column change is like this,

```
<td class="click" id="clickTest2">
<script>
$("#clickTest2").click({param1: "content2", param2: "One more text area Hurrey!!!"}, cool_function);
</script>
<div>
    <img id='' src="file://c://gray.jpg"/>
</div>
<div id='content2' title='Ketan B' style="display:none;">
    <div><textarea>One more text area Hurrey!!!</textarea></div>
</div>
```

and Script change is like this,

```
function cool_function(event){
$('#'+event.data.param1).dialog({
    model : true,
    buttons: {
        "Save": function() {
            alert('Content Will be Saved');
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        "Cancel":  function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the content ? Is there a purpose to you needing it later being bound to the same click event  ?

Comment: Never mind , i understand now, after the first click , you are not getting the pop up window on subsequent clicks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so i have gone through the whole code that you had provided, and it was way too much complex.. too many recursive calls. So i made the code a little simple and instead of calling the modal recursively (which in fact leads to the un binding of the `content` from the dialog), i segregated stuff like this :

**HTML:**

```
<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
      <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
      <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
        <thead>
          <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
            <td>johndoe1</td>
            <td class="click" id="clickTest1">
              <div>
                <img id='' src="http://www.eventbelladesigns.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderpictures/gray.jpg"/>
              </div>
              <div id='content1' title='John Doe' style="display:none;">
                <div><textarea>Hello this is Text Area</textarea></div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ketan B</td>
            <td>ketan.b@example.com</td>
            <td>ket1</td>
            <td class="click" id="clickTest2">
              <div>
                <img id='' src="http://www.eventbelladesigns.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderpictures/gray.jpg"/>
              </div>
              <div id='content2' title='Ketan B' style="display:none;">
                <div><textarea>One more text area Hurrey!!!</textarea></div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#clickTest1").on('click', callModal1);
$("#clickTest2").on('click', callModal2);

function callModal1(){
  $(function() {
    $( "#content1" ).dialog(({
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        }
      ]
    }));
  });
}

function callModal2(){
  $(function() {
    $( "#content2" ).dialog(({
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        }
      ]
    }));
  });
}
```

Here, once the call happens , the modal/dialog  will open, but once you close the dialog by clicking on the close icon or the cancel button, the content will not be un loaded and the dialogues will still appear during subsequent clicks.

I have binned it  out for you, you can see the working solution at : http://jsbin.com/oxucak/1/edit. And remember  to `run with js`.

Comment: Buddy, Thanks... Actually I need this thing dynamic (as I number of rows may very). And that is why I tried to build this example such a way that single function to be called to open the dialog and input element for that specific row will be open and filled. I got my answer from your simplified working version of same. Once again thanks for your help..

Comment: @Ketan : Happy to have helped some how . Glad you found the solution .